# React component folder use for external controls

Tags: reactjs

I have a video player component situated in the components folder of a React project

```
function ReactVideoPlayer(){
const [url] = useState('https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4');
  const [controls, setControls] = useState([
    'play',
    'time',
    'progress',
    'volume',
    'full-screen'
  ]);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(0.7);
  const [timeStart] = useState(5);
```

I then have that component embedded in index.js simply as

```
    > return (
    >     <div>    
<ReactVideoPlayer    />
    >     </div>
```

This player works fine if I have the url on the component page.
But can someone please explain to me how you move the video url from the component page to the index page eg

```
<ReactVideoPlayer
url='https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4'
   />
```

This does not work but hopefully you get the idea.
I am trying to work out how to build components and then use them more than once in a page.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `props` instead of hardcoding the video in the component:

```
function ReactVideoPlayer(props){
const url = props.url;
```

or, with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function ReactVideoPlayer(props){
const {url} = props;
```

or, destructuring directly in the arguments (this is how I prefer to do it)

```
function ReactVideoPlayer({url}){
// just use url
```

Comment: Mate your a legend! Thanks solved my little issue!

Comment: Great to hear it - Please mark my answer as accepted :)